# Unable to configure Azure Event Hub Producer

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-eventhub

I am trying a sample code of Azure Event Hub Producer and trying to send some message to Azure Event Hub.

The eventhub and its policy is correctly configured for sending and listening messages. I am using Dotnet core 3.1 console application. However, the code doesn't move beyond CreateBatchAsync() call. I tried debugging and the breakpoint doesn't go to next line. Tried Try-catch-finally and still no progress. Please guide what I am doing wrong here. The Event hub on Azure is shows some number of successful incoming requests.

```cs
    class Program
    {
        private const string connectionString = "<event_hub_connection_string>";
        private const string eventHubName = "<event_hub_name>";
        static async Task Main()
        {
            // Create a producer client that you can use to send events to an event hub
            await using (var producerClient = new EventHubProducerClient(connectionString, eventHubName))
            {
                // Create a batch of events 
                using EventDataBatch eventBatch = await producerClient.CreateBatchAsync();

                // Add events to the batch. An event is a represented by a collection of bytes and metadata. 
                eventBatch.TryAdd(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("First event")));
                eventBatch.TryAdd(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Second event")));
                eventBatch.TryAdd(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Third event")));

                // Use the producer client to send the batch of events to the event hub
                await producerClient.SendAsync(eventBatch);
                Console.WriteLine("A batch of 3 events has been published.");
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: The code that I am using is below - https://github.com/MarczakIO/azure4everyone-samples/blob/master/azure-eventhubs-introduction/01-SendEvents/Program.cs

Comment: As an unrelated note, I'd strongly advise that you not ignore the return from `TryAdd`;  doing so could lead to data loss.

Comment: Sure. I will capture that information. I am noob here and trying a sample so that I get confidence to migrate my webjob into this for queue management. I will definitely ensure that there is no data loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `CreateBatchAsync` would be the first need to create a connection to Event Hubs.  This indicates that you're likely experiencing a connectivity or authorization issue.

In the default configuration you're using, the default network timeout is 60 seconds and up to 3 retries are possible, with some back-off between them.

Because of this, a failure to connect or authorize may take up to roughly 5 minutes before it manifests.  That said, the majority of connection errors are not eligible for retries, so the failure would normally surface after roughly 1 minute.

To aid in your debugging, I'd suggest tweaking the default retry policy to speed things up and surface an exception more quickly so that you have the information needed to troubleshoot and make adjustments.   The options to do so are discussed in [this sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/samples/Sample02_EventHubsClients.md#configuring-the-client-retry-thresholds) and would look something like:

```cs
var connectionString = "<< CONNECTION STRING FOR THE EVENT HUBS NAMESPACE >>";
var eventHubName = "<< NAME OF THE EVENT HUB >>";

var options = new EventHubProducerClientOptions
{
    RetryOptions = new EventHubsRetryOptions
    {
        // Allow the network operation only 15 seconds to complete.
        TryTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),

        // Turn off retries        
        MaximumRetries = 0,
        Mode = EventHubsRetryMode.Fixed,
        Delay = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10),
        MaximumDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
    }
};

await using var producer = new EventHubProducerClient(
    connectionString,
    eventHubName,
    options);
```

Comment: The event hub on Azure shows successfull incoming requests. This could be still a connectivity issue?

Comment: Yes.   In the absence of an exception to debug, a problem establishing connectivity is the most likely cause here.

Comment: Alright.  Let me explore this and come back. Thank you so much for the assistance

Comment: Hi there, I tried configuring the retry options and the problem still persists. I thought of adding getawaiter().getresult() and that also didn't worked. ValueTaskAwaiter<EventBatchData> does not contain definition for 'GetAwaiter'

Comment: The next step would be to enable SDK log capture so that we can see what's going on from the client's perspective.  Steps to do so are described in [this sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/samples/Sample10_AzureEventSourceListener.md).  Once you've captured logs, I'd suggest opening an issue in the Azure SDK for .NET repository: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issue.  That would give us a better platform for a longer discussion as we attempt to narrow things down.

Comment: Sure. I am doing that. Also I feel authorization and connection is not a problem. I can see that requests are successful on Azure. My machine is able to make successful connection  requests to the hub - https://ibb.co/dmJDsyg
Also, I will try with other versions of library and on a different computer

Comment: I enabled the sdk level logging and got the following output. Does it means that it is working fine?

```[Informational] Azure-Messaging-EventHubs: Publishing events for Event Hub: mydemo (Partition Id/Key: '', Event Hash: '20735233').
Successful!```

Comment: This time I tried sending data one event at a time instead of batch and looks like it worked. I will also try to consume this data and see if it works. Sure, batch creation is a problem which I need to solve via github issue reporting. If the consumer works fine, I will upvote your answer as "the answer" and request some edits

Comment: That log indicates that an attempt to publish has started, but not that it completed.   I don't know where "Successful!" came from - that's not part of our messaging.  You'll be looking for event #4 with a message like `Completed publishing events for Event Hub: {0} (Partition Id/Key: '{1}'), Operation Id: '{2}'.  Service Retry Count: {3}.`    There is also a potential for #5, which would tell you if an error took place.

Comment: The problem solved. Please don't get me wrong but I was not calling the methods correctly. The method was returning void instead of returning Task. I am sorry.

Comment: No need for apologies.   I'm glad that things got sorted out and you're unblocked.   :)